# .SQL Server 2012 - sa password unaccessible

Tags: password-reset

Just installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and Microsoft Server Management Studio on computer and am trying to connect databases to the server.  The server was set up with Windows Authentication, but the software automatically assigned a password to the sa, and I've been unable to change the password in the Configuration Manager.  The status is enabled.  How do I access or change the password for sa ?

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all the possible passwords and still no luck, you should reset the password through the backdoor method.  Steps can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj853293.aspx